# Did anyone create the Java Code Formatter Profile for Eclipse IDE that conforms to the Android Code Style Rules?

Tags: android, eclipse, coding-style

Android [Code Style Guide](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) defines "Android Code Style Rules".
To conform to these rules one have to change quite a number of settings of the Java Code Formatter (Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter) default profile (in Eclipse IDE).

Did anyone manage to configure the formatter to follow the "Android Code Style Rules" already?
If yes, please export the Formatter profile and publish to be used by community.

PS: I've tried to do this myself but I've found that there are too many formatter options available, and most of them are not mentioned in the Code Style Guide :-(

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are pre-made formatter rules available from the [platform/development.git](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development.git) repository ([GitHub mirror](https://github.com/android/platform_development), in folder [/ide/eclipse](https://github.com/android/platform_development/tree/master/ide/eclipse)).

So you can simply import [android-formatting.xml](https://raw.github.com/android/platform_development/master/ide/eclipse/android-formatting.xml) and [android.importorder](https://raw.github.com/android/platform_development/master/ide/eclipse/android.importorder) as mentioned [here](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html).

Comment: Thank you, kroimon, very much!
This is exactly what I was dreaming of :-) - these are "live" documents that continue improving as the Android ecosystem matures.

Comment: So what are the new code style guidelines? Where can we find them?

Comment: @kaciula The guidelines can now be found at: https://raw.github.com/android/platform_development/master/ide/eclipse/android-formatting.xml (https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/ide/eclipse/)

Comment: Thank you, @ninetwozero. I just updated the answer with the latest links.

Answer (score 6):

On a related note, here's how developers around Google keep their various Eclipse instances all in agreement: [Workspace Mechanic for Eclipse](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2010/05/introducing-workspace-mechanic-for.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think personal or team preferences vary to much to globally enforce a coding style. So every body should deploy his project specific coding style.

Comment: I agree, but it's much easier to start from the "globally enforced  code style rules" and change them only in those areas that are really important to the person or team,
comparing to starting from "as is" and then trying to figure out how far this state is from "globally inforced code style rules"?!

Comment: I disagree.  When people need to switch from one project to another, trying to read code which looks different can mess you up.  Plus, there are some things that *nonone* should do really (like having two lines of an if statement without using curly braces) and you have to enforce these things to prevent possible logic bombs

Answer (score 1):

The link in kroimon's answer to android formatter rules is broken. [Here](http://source.android.com/source/using-eclipse.html) is the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Sync the source code according to [these instructions](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html).
The formatting guidelines are in the file development/ide/eclipse/android-formatting.xml. You can import it with Eclipse.

Menu bar -> Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Import

Point it to the path of the android-formatting.xml