# Can Eclipse's Java formatter indent wrapped lines differently than new blocks?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

I like to format my code like this:

```
void someFunction() {
   normalLine();
   reallyLongLineThatNeedsToBeWrapped(
    OnlyIndentOneSpaceHere = true);
   normalLine();
}
```

But from my experimenting with Eclipse's source formatting, it seems that you can't specify wrapped line indentation independently from new block indentation.

Is there a way to accomplish this in Eclipse?

Per answer, I submitted an [Eclipse enhancement request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367893).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. The problem is you can't change the indentation size to be different depending on context. So choosing 1 for the indentation size results in everything being indented by one space. You can have a separate wrapping policy based on it being a function call or not, but the "units" of indentation can't change if it's a function call.

Comment: Even if I wouldn't be able to customize the indentation, I think the default behavior should be changed:

At the moment automatic indentation of this:

    private static final String X =
        "foo";

Gets changed to this:

    private static final String X =
    "foo"; 

Which I think is just plain **wrong**.   All continuation lines should be indented.

Comment: You can file a bug report against Eclipse JDT to bring this to their attention.

Comment: Turns out that while that is the default behavior, there IS a way to make it do something reasonable.  
<br>
Preferences->Java->Code Style->Formatter->Edit  
<br>
Go to the `Line Wrapping` tab (or some other Java source context in the last).   Then select "assignments" (under "expressions"), and then (at the bottom of the panel) choose settings that suit your tastes.  

What is provided there, seems sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

It is possible to indent wrapped lines differently but there is a limitation: Indentation for wrapped lines has to be multiple of indentation for blocks.

You're specifically asking to set block indentation to 3 and line wrap indentation to 1. This particular setup is **not** possible as of now.

So, what if you want to use, for example, [Google Java Style](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html)? Their block indentation is 2 and wrapped line (continuation) indent is 4. This is **achiavable** since 4 is a multiple of 2.

First, open the formatter settings:

`Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit`

In the Indentation tab, set Indentation size to 2. This is the block indentation.

Then open the `Line Wrapping` tab. There you have *Default indentation for wrapped lines* and *Default indentation for array initializers*. Set these fields to 2, meaning wrapped lines indentation will be twice the block indentation.