# Set Indentation between Parenthesis for Java's try-with-resources in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, indentation

I like to format Java's try-with-resources as follows:

```
try
(
   FileInputStream     input   = new FileInputStream("data.txt");
   BufferedInputStream buffer  = new BufferedInputStream(input);
   InputStreamReader   convert = new InputStreamReader(buffer);
   LineNumberReader    parse   = new LineNumberReader(convert);
)
{
   // process the data in the file
}
```

To start, I write the following with the caret between the parenthesis:

```
try
(|)
```

I then hit the enter key and Eclipse formats the code as this:

```
try
(
         )
```

The closing parenthesis is 9 spaces to the right.  My indentation settings are set to use 3 spaces.  How do I configure Eclipse to do the following when hitting the enter key?

```
try
(

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is governed by Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Line Wrapping -> Default indentation for wrapped lines. (Set to 0 to achieve the desired effect)

Unfortunately, AFAIK it is not possible to set different indentation depending on context (i.e. you can't set it only for `try`, it will be for all wrapping).

See a couple of related questions:
[Can the Eclipse formatter be configured to indent multiple lines between parenthesis properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186714/can-the-eclipse-formatter-be-configured-to-indent-multiple-lines-between-parenth)
[Can Eclipse's Java formatter indent wrapped lines differently than new blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686252/can-eclipses-java-formatter-indent-wrapped-lines-differently-than-new-blocks)

Comment: This is very close to ideal.  I'll wait a bit before awarding this answer just in case someone comes with an even better answer.  The only problem is that there is no indentation for the line.  Oh well, this is much better than the 8 characters it was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Like Edwin (nice profile picture) said, eclipse behaves this way because most sane code would want to be indented in that case.

You can disable this feature by going to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing, and then unchecking the "Enter key adjusts the indentation on the new line" checkbox under the Indentation section:

[image]

Note that this will disable all of the auto-indenting, which also seems to disable nice features like inserting closing curly brackets, so it's probably not worth it.

You might also consider creating a template by going to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Templates. You might modify the existing `try` template, although my quick tinkering shows that the indent is always added, even when I have the above checkbox unchecked.

Comment: It solves the problem but as you noted it introduces several more problems.  The cure isn't worth the side effects.