# java eclipse formatting (unnecessary white space if condition )

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

On formatting my code Ctrl + Shift + f
This is how my code looks

```
if (item == null) {}
```

Is it possible to get it formatted like

```
if(item == null) {}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go to Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > formatter > Edit > and uncheck option "before opening parenthesis".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can configure [formatting profiles](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcodestyle%2Fref-preferences-formatter.htm) on Eclipse.

Just go to Eclipse preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter.

As the other answer specifies (damn it, that was fast!) you'll find the particular option you're looking for on the `before opening parenthesis` checkbox displayed when selecting `control statements > 'if else'` on the `white space` tab on the `edit profile` dialog.

Check out these resources too:

http://www.ralfebert.de/archive/java/source_formatting/

[Best Eclipse Code Formatters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754405/best-eclipse-code-formatters)