# User defined Eclipse formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

Under the braces option , i have used all the properties to set to sameline. But on the Blank lines option, Number of empty lines to preserve is 1 . This is overriding my existing property.

**Expected:**

```
public class SamplePreparedStatement {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
```

**Actual**

```
public class SamplePreparedStatement {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException

{
```

Settings:

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.insert_new_line_before_root_tags" value="insert"/>
    <setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_opening_brace_in_type_declaration" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_comma_in_type_arguments" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.brace_position_for_anonymous_type_declaration" value="end_of_line"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_before_colon_in_case" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_brace_in_array_initializer" value="insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.comment.new_lines_at_block_boundaries" value="true"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_before_closing_brace_in_array_initializer" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_opening_paren_in_annotation" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.blank_lines_before_field" value="0"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.use_on_off_tags" value="false"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_between_empty_parens_in_annotation_type_member_declaration" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_new_line_before_else_in_if_statement" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.insert_space_after_prefix_operator" value="do not insert"/>
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.keep_else_statement_on_same_line" value="false"/>
```

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754405/best-eclipse-code-formatters

Comment: That does not help me out. basically, it is overwriting the option option.

Comment: Did you create "New Profile" on formatter screen at the first?

Comment: @javapointdotcom please export and post your settings XML

Comment: any answers for my question ?

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse menu Window - > Preferences -> Java -> Code Style ->Formatter

then import your current for-matter into eclipse and follow the below steps.

**Window - > Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter**

Then click on Edit button a pup window will open. Again it has multiple tabs click on Braces.

Under which Class or interface declaration there will be a drop down box in which select **Same line** option.

Then save your for-matter post that changes will reflect.

Comment: Already , i have used that only .. Using 2 formatter options is overriding the other one. Please check the xml posted.

Comment: any answers for my question ?

Comment: I know to remove the empty line but asking about any other approach where the eclipse should do it instead of manual approach.